# Can I say "you are all considered of the same roots"?

Tags: word-usage

I wrote 2 sentences:

Many ethnic groups migrated into Vietnamese territory at different historical periods: some came thousands of years ago, fairly early, and others hundreds of years ago. Regardless of that, once you have lived on the S-shaped strip of land*, you are **all considered of the same roots** and are compatriots united by mutual understanding, allegiance, attachment and care.

*Vietnam is a long, narrow nation shaped like the letter S.

The problems is in bold

All considered of the same roots: In Vietnam, we have this popular myth that any Vietnamese is a descendant of the legendary couple AU CO (the Fairy) and LAC LONG QUAN (the Dragon). But in English, we are sensitive about origins of ethnicity and race so I don't want to deny any of the 53 Vietnamese minor ethnic groups' origin by saying they are also from that root as they may have different myths about their origin. That's why I used the phrase "is considered". The sense I'm trying to imply is that However, I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Comment: Strictly speaking, 'territory' is a political term; it could be argued that 'Vietnamese territory' had no meaning until 1945, 1954, or 1975. Certainly not 'thousands of years ago'. You might want to say 'Many ethnic groups migrated into **what is now** Vietnamese territory'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a reasonable way to describe what you want, although a few grammatical alterations are needed.

I would write it as:

> once you have lived on the S-shaped strip of land*, you are <s>all</s> considered **to be** of the same roots and <s>are</s> compatriots united by mutual understanding, allegiance, attachment and care.

As the writer you are speaking directly to the reader, so don't say "you *all*", just say '*you*'. The auxiliary verb *to be* is needed here. The second 'are' isn't needed as it becomes a list item.

You are right that matters around ethnicity and race are sensitive, but mainly for the reason that we need to respect and understand different cultures. What you are describing *is* a culture. You are saying that it is the culture in Vietnam to think of people this way, and so the reader must surely respect that.

Comment: I would suggest _'come from_ the same roots'.

Comment: @KateBunting I disagree, I think that is too literal.